# Htaccess (mod_rewrite) for category and page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URL:

```
index.php?kategorie=SOME-CATEGORY-NAME&stranka=NUMBER-OF-PAGE
```

and I want to have this URL

```
kategorie/SOME-CATEGORY-NAME/stranka/NUMBER-OF-PAGE
```

I was checking tutorials for over hour but I still don't know how to do it, i think it should be

```
RewriteRule ^kategorie\/([0-9a-zA-Z\-\_]+)\/stranka\/(.*)$ index.php?kategorie=$1&stranka=$2 [L,QSA]
```

but this doesnt work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^kategorie\/([0-9a-zA-Z\-\_]+)\/stranka\/(.*)$ index.php?kategorie=$1&stranka=$2 [L,QSA]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^kategorie/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/stranka/(.*)$ index.php?kategorie=$1&stranka=$2 [L,QSA]
```

should work, you don't need to escape (`\`) the forward slashes (`/`) on the RewriteRule.

Comment: sorry, still doesnt work... can you please check if there isnt any other poblem?

Comment: What happens when you enter a url like "kategorie/SOME-CATEGORY-NAME/stranka/NUMBER-OF-PAGE"?